# tensorflow loss is nan while training an RNN

Tags: python, tensorflow

Running an RNN with a single GRU cell, I'm running into situations where I get the following stacktrace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "language_model_test.py", line 15, in <module>
    test_model()
  File "language_model_test.py", line 12, in test_model
    model.train(random_data, s)
  File "/home/language_model/language_model.py", line 120, in train
    train_pp = self._run_epoch(data, sess, inputs, rnn_ouputs, loss, trainOp, verbose)
  File "/home/language_model/language_model.py", line 92, in _run_epoch
    loss, _= sess.run([loss, trainOp], feed_dict=feed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 767, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 952, in _run
    fetch_handler = _FetchHandler(self._graph, fetches, feed_dict_string)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 408, in __init__
    self._fetch_mapper = _FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetches)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 230, in for_fetch
    return _ListFetchMapper(fetch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 337, in __init__
    self._mappers = [_FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetch) for fetch in fetches]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 238, in for_fetch
    return _ElementFetchMapper(fetches, contraction_fn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 271, in __init__
    % (fetch, type(fetch), str(e)))
TypeError: Fetch argument nan has invalid type <type 'numpy.float32'>, must be a string or Tensor. (Can not convert a float32 into a Tensor or Operation.)
```

The step for calculating loss appears to be the issue

```
def train(self,data, session=tf.Session(), verbose=10):

        print "initializing model"
        self._add_placeholders()
        inputs = self._add_embedding()
        rnn_ouputs, _ = self._run_rnn(inputs)
        outputs = self._projection_layer(rnn_ouputs)
        loss = self._compute_loss(outputs)
        trainOp = self._add_train_step(loss)
        start = tf.initialize_all_variables()
        saver = tf.train.Saver()

        with session as sess:
            sess.run(start)

            for epoch in xrange(self._max_epochs):
                train_pp = self._run_epoch(data, sess, inputs, rnn_ouputs, loss, trainOp, verbose)
                print "Training preplexity for batch {} - {}".format(epoch, train_pp)
```

Here is the code for `_run_epoch`

Any place with loss comes back `nan`

```
def _run_epoch(self, data, session, inputs, rnn_ouputs, loss, trainOp, verbose=10):
    with session.as_default() as sess:
        total_steps = sum(1 for x in data_iterator(data, self._batch_size, self._max_steps))
        train_loss = []
        for step, (x,y, l) in enumerate(data_iterator(data, self._batch_size, self._max_steps)):
            print "step - {0}".format(step)
            feed = {
                self.input_placeholder: x,
                self.label_placeholder: y,
                self.sequence_length: l,
                self._dropout_placeholder: self._dropout,
            }
            loss, _= sess.run([loss, trainOp], feed_dict=feed)
            print "loss - {0}".format(loss)
            train_loss.append(loss)
            if verbose and step % verbose == 0:
                sys.stdout.write('\r{} / {} : pp = {}'. format(step, total_steps, np.exp(np.mean(train_loss))))
                sys.stdout.flush()
            if verbose:
                sys.stdout.write('\r')

        return np.exp(np.mean(train_loss))
```

This is arising when I test my code by using the following for my data
`random_data = np.random.normal(0, 100, size=[42068, 46])` which is designed to mimic using word ids to pass around as inputs. The rest of my code can be found in the following [gist](https://gist.github.com/IoDmitri/499b8273d4504bec0ace61f39ce1a7c3)

**EDIT** Here is the way that I run the test suit where this issue arises:

```
def test_model():
    model = Language_model(vocab=range(0,101))
    s = tf.Session()
    #1 more than step size to acoomodate for the <eos> token at the end
    random_data = np.random.normal(0, 100, size=[42068, 46])
    # file = "./data/ptb.test.txt"
    print "Fitting started"
    model.train(random_data, s)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_model()
```

If I substitute `random_data` into other language models, they will also output `nan` for the cost. My understanding is that tensorflow, via passing in the feed-dict, should be taking the numeric values and retrieving the appropriate embedding vector corresponding to the id, I'm not understand why the `random_data` is causing `nan`'s for other models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with the code above

lets start with this line

```
random_data = np.random.normal(0, 100, size=[42068, 46])
```

`np.random.normal(...)` doesn't produce distinct values, it rather produces float values, lets try the following example above, but with a manageable size.

```
>>> np.random.normal(0, 100, size=[5])
array([-53.12407229,  39.57335574, -98.25406749,  90.81471139, -41.05069646])
```

There's no way a machine learning algorithm could learn those since those are meant to be inputs to an embedding model and we've got negative values along with floating point values.

What is actually wanted is the following code:

```
random_data = np.random.randint(0, 101, size=...)
```

Checking its output we get

```
>>> np.random.randint(0, 100, size=[5])
array([27, 47, 33, 12, 24])
```

Next, the following line is actually creating a subtle problem.

```
def _run_epoch(self, data, session, inputs, rnn_ouputs, loss, train, verbose=10):
    with session.as_default() as sess:
        total_steps = sum(1 for x in data_iterator(data, self._batch_size, self._max_steps))
        train_loss = []
        for step, (x,y, l) in enumerate(data_iterator(data, self._batch_size, self._max_steps)):
            print "step - {0}".format(step)
            feed = {
                self.input_placeholder: x,
                self.label_placeholder: y,
                self.sequence_length: l,
                self._dropout_placeholder: self._dropout,
            }
            loss, _= sess.run([loss, train], feed_dict=feed)
            print "loss - {0}".format(loss)
            train_loss.append(loss)
            if verbose and step % verbose == 0:
                sys.stdout.write('\r{} / {} : pp = {}'. format(step, total_steps, np.exp(np.mean(train_loss))))
                sys.stdout.flush()
            if verbose:
                sys.stdout.write('\r')

        return np.exp(np.mean(train_loss))
```

`loss` is both a parameter argument and a variable, so the first time its run, it will no longer be a tensor and so we can't actually call it in a session.